# Como recorrer nodos con un foreach en C#

Tags: c#, xml

Vengo en busca de consejo o ayuda, pues deseo realizar una función que tengo en VB en C# pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

```
int Partida = 1
VarConceptos = VarDocumentoXML.SelectNodes("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto", VarManager)

    For Each node In VarConceptos
        Producto(Partida) = node.attributes("NoIdentificacion").value
        cveSAT(Partida) = node.attributes("ClaveProdServ").value
        Descripcion(Partida) = node.attributes("Descripcion").value
        unidad(Partida) = node.attributes("ClaveUnidad").value
        Cantidad(Partida) = node.attributes("Cantidad").value
        precio(Partida) = node.attributes("ValorUnitario").value
        subtotal(Partida) = node.attributes("Importe").value
next
```

en C# el node no contiene la propiedad attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, hay que especificar de que tipo es node:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in varConceptos)
        {
            Producto[Partida] = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["NoIdentificacion"].Value);
        }
```